# String Compare in If statement VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was hoping to find out how to compare strings in an If statement in VBA.

I want to use a string compare in an if statement in order to create an array of unique strings from an array with repeated strings

Ex: [x,y,y,z,z,z] -> [x,y,z]

```
Dim A() As String = {"abc","abc","abc","def","def","ghi"}
Dim Alength As Long = Len(A)
Dim tempcounter As Integer = 0
Dim B As String()


For i = 1 To Alength

If i = 1 Then
    tempcounter = tempcounter + 1
    ReDim Preserve B(tempcounter) As String
    B(tempcounter) = A(i)


ElseIf i > 1 Then
    If A(i) <> A(i - 1) Then

        tempcounter = tempcounter + 1
        ReDim Preserve B(tempcounter) As String
        B(tempcounter) = A(i)
    End If
End If
Next
```

With this code, B returns as a copy of A. I want B to end up as ("abc","def","ghi")

I tried using a string compare in the if statement, such as:
StrComp(A(i),A(i-1)), but I cannot get this to work.

What do I need to do to get the string compare to function how i intend it to?

Comment: ...Wait a minute, did you mean **VB.Net**? The code you posted wouldn't even compile in VBA. VBA doesn't support array literals with curly brackets, nor does it support inline initialization of variables.

Comment: Yes, I was coding in VBA. I am not too familiar with the syntax of this language and I am struggling with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the way you define arrays. In fact you code won't even run in VBA. I have edited you code so it will run as described.

```
Sub CompareString()
    Dim A() As Variant
    Dim Alength As Long
    Dim B() As String
    Dim TempCounter As Integer
    Dim Flag As Boolean

    A = Array("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi")
    TempCounter = 0
    ReDim B(0 To 0)

    'Loops through A
    For i = 0 To UBound(A) Step 1
        Flag = False

        'Loops through B
        For j = 0 To UBound(B) Step 1
            If A(i) = B(j) Then
                Flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        'If the element was not found in B it will be added
        If Flag = False Then
            ReDim Preserve B(0 To TempCounter)
            B(UBound(B)) = A(i)
            TempCounter = TempCounter + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to get this working as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A vastly faster approach would be to use a `Dictionary` object. Here's my `Unique` method. You will need a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'  Returns an array containing unique items in the source enumerable object
'  by using identity comparison built in to the Dictionary object. Preserves
'  all object types; also string "1" will not equal number 1
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function Unique(ByRef EnumerableObject)
    Dim oHash As New Dictionary
    Dim vItem
    For Each vItem In EnumerableObject
        oHash(vItem) = True
    Next
    Unique = oHash.Keys
End Function
```